# Adapter and Dynamic data in Drawer

Tags: android

I am new to Android programming and facing some issues.

I want to achieve this

[image]

this is my view on website. I am trying to implement the same on android. 
[image]

This much is done but I am unable to proceed further and I am stuck with the Button thing. These are the drawers and data is set using Adapter.

My activity_main.xml file

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context="com.gyanibano.drawerlayout.MainActivity">
    <include layout="@layout/app_bar"/>
        <ListView
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_left"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff">

        </ListView>
        <ListView
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_right"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff">
        </ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My gdmainleft.xml file

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_set"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sideColor"
            android:layout_width="8dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="#88FF0000"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/count"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="26sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My CustomerAdapter.java file

```
public class CustomerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    String result[];
    Context context;
    String counts[];
    int img[], colr[];
    int no;
    int showquest;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public CustomerAdapter(String[] result, Context context, String[] counts, int[] img, int colr[], int no, int showquest) {
        this.result = result;
        this.context = context;
        this.counts = counts;
        this.img = img;
        this.colr = colr;
        this.no = no;
        this.showquest = showquest;
        inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final holder hld = new holder();
        View rowview, questview;
        if(no==1) {
            rowview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gdmainright, null);
            hld.tv = (TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.txt);
            hld.tv.setText(result[i]);
        }
        else{

            rowview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gdmainleft, null);
            hld.tv = (TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.txt);
            hld.tv.setText(result[i]);

            hld.tv = (TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.count);
            hld.tv.setText(counts[i]);

            hld.tv = (TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.sideColor);
            hld.tv.setBackgroundColor(colr[i]);

            hld.iv = (ImageView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            hld.iv.setImageResource(img[i]);
        }
        return rowview;
    }

    public class holder{
        TextView tv;
        ImageView iv;
        Button bt;
    }

}
```

My MainActivity.java file

```
                usercount = jObj.getInt("usercount");
                mcqcount = jObj.getInt("mcqcount");
                keywordscount = jObj.getInt("keywordscount");
                papercount = jObj.getInt("papercount");
                showquest = jObj.getInt("showquest");

                Tags = " QnA, Tags, Papers, Users";
                tagname = Tags.split(",");

                Counts = mcqcount+","+keywordscount+","+papercount+","+usercount;
                countvalue = Counts.split(",");

                Imgs = new int[]{R.drawable.qm, R.drawable.tg, R.drawable.bk, R.drawable.usr};

                Colr = new int[]{Color.rgb(255,0,0), Color.rgb(255, 165, 0),Color.rgb(102,204,87), Color.rgb(0,0,255)};

                cl3 = new CustomerAdapter(tagname, con, countvalue, Imgs, Colr, 2, showquest);
                drawer_left.setAdapter(cl3);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, but it looks like you're asking someone to write some code for you. Stack overflow exists to help people with legitimate problems, not write code that can be found using Google.

Comment: No, I am not asking someone to write code for me. But, to suggest me some way using which I would be able to achieve it.